# String manipulation in C?

Tags: c, sorting

Okay I am trying to ask and sort names in C. I completed the code and it compiled without an error but I have a problem. When I input mixed characters that is Uppercase and Lowercase I get Uppercase sorted first and not in order. What should I do to my code ? Please anyone help me.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30][25],temp[25];
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter how many students : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the student : ");
        scanf("%s",name[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name[i],name[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i],name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sorted names are : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short input and the corresponding output, it ill help figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: You should use an array of pointers, and you want to use `qsort`

Comment: Maybe convert your strings to lowercase before comparing them?

Comment: You want to sort case-insignificant? Use `strcasecmp()`

Comment: @larsks if I do so the output will be lowercase and I want it to appear exactly as it is entered !

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;i++);`?

Comment: Someone suggested "convert your strings to lowercase before comparing them."  You replied "I don't get you".  Someone else suggested `strcasecmp()`.  Here's why you're seeing this problem.  The letters `a` through `z` use ASCII codes 97 through 122.  The letters `A` through `Z` use ASCII codes  65 through 90.  Comparisons usually follow the ASCII value.  So of course the sorting is case sensitive.  This is why you're having this problem with your homework assignment.  The solution is to compare case-insensitively or use a smarter collation utility.

Answer (score 1):

The loops for your bubble sort are wrong - change:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i+j;j<n;j++)
    {
```

to:

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
```

Alternatively just use [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) from the standard C library rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Why the anonymous down-vote, I wonder ? Is there something wrong with the above fix ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One, convert the string to lower (or upper) before comparison. Secondly strcol each string, this puts k next to K etc. Both methods are destructive so you may need to create a work string and free it after comparison.

Comment: It is also feasible to use a standard case-insensitive string comparator function (`strcasecmp()` in POSIX, `stricmp()` for Windows, IIRC).  Using `strcoll()` (with two `l`'s) is an interesting idea; it is not destructive, though.  The `strxfrm()` function is the interesting one, and even it is non-destructive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your program is wrong. For example instead of

```
scanf("%s",&name[i]);
```

there has to be

```
scanf("%s", name[i]);
```

Or in this statement

```
for(j=i+j;j<n;j++)
```

there is used uninitialized variable j.

As for your question then you should convert strings to upper case using standard C function `toupper` declared in header `<ctype.h>`

Also it is better to use selection sort without copying strings every time when name[j] is less than name[i].

Comment: @starrify Do you understand what is the difference between &name[i] and name[i] and what are their types?

Comment: I understand that `&name[i]` and `name[i]` are different things. But again I tell you in this case the two are both very fine to be used with `scanf`. It's like passing a `int[10]` and a `int*` to a function that accepts `int*`.

Comment: @starrify No you are wrong. Though they have the same value &name[i] has invalid type for specifier $s. You have to use correct types. C++ Allows sometimes to use bad construction bit it does not mean that you should use them.

Comment: @starrify So your comment is wrong and advices to use wrong constructtions.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you for pointing this out. And sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors:

do not end the for loop with a semicolon

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
```

take a second look at these variables

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
```

as you described you compare incorrectly for your usecase

```
if(strcmp(name[i],name[j])>0)
```

This is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * Inputs[] = 
{
    "3\n",
    "Carl\n",
    "Frank\n",
    "carl\n"
};

int in = 0;


int main()
{
    char name[30][25],temp[25];
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter how many students : \n");
    sscanf(Inputs[in++],"%i",&n);
    printf("You entered : %i\n", n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the student : \n");
        sscanf(Inputs[in++],"%s",&name[i]);
        printf("You entered : %s\n", name[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(stricmp(name[i],name[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,name[i]);
                strcpy(name[i],name[j]);
                strcpy(name[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The sorted names are : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```